# regex for below text

Tags: regex

> (Q3 Un-audited): EPU was Tk. 0.28 for January-March 2018 as against
>   Tk. 0.10 for January-March 2017; EPU was Tk. 0.50 for July 2017-March
>   2018 as against Tk. 0.43 for July 2016-March 2017. NOCFPU was Tk. 0.48
>   for July 2017-March 2018 as against Tk. 0.35 for July 2016-March 2017.
>   NAV per unit at market price was Tk. 11.21 as on March 31, 2018 and
>   Tk. 12.06 as on June 30, 2017. NAV per unit at cost price was Tk.
>   11.01 as on March 31, 2018 and Tk. 11.54 as on June 30, 2017

from above code I would like to get all numerice [0.28,2018,0.10,2017,0.50,2017,2018,etc]

How can I do that

Comment: Did you try anything - if so please show it. Also, please add the tag of the language/tool you are using. btw, try this: `\d+(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[`\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gH8d4E/1)

This gives almost the same results as Daniele Cappuccio's answer but will not match digits next to letters (like `Q9`).

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```